# Control the flow with logical operator in Julia

Tags: while-loop, julia, boolean-expression

I am trying to run a `while` cycle with `or` and `and` conditions in Julia.

In Python I could do

```
while something and somethingelse:
    staff happens
```

And the same thing with the `or`. But in Julia, even using the `|` and `&` operators, it doesn't seems to work, i.e.

```
t=0
while s != 0 & d <= N
   t+=1
   something happens
end
```

For the `&` condition, I made it work by using an `if` with the `brake` condition i.e.

```
t=0
while s != 0
  something happens
  t+=1
  if d>N
    break
  end
end
```

But I have no idea how to make it work for the `or`.

If it can be done in a single line, even better.

Comment: In both of your examples, the mocked up loop bodies don't modify any of the variables that the while loop's termination depends on. If that's actually the case in your code, then it's no surprise that these loops don't terminate – they would either execute zero times or forever.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've not been clear enough. The loop is actually part of another if cycle which implements the 's', where s is the length of an array randomly filled with 1, and N is a fixed number. That's why the program works in the second case.

Comment: If you want an answer that addresses this, you may need to update your question to clarify.

Answer (score 4):

In Julia `&` actually performs bitwise-and and `|` performs bitwise-or. These operators have [higher precedence](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/mathematical-operations/#operator-precedence) than comparison operators so your condition is evaluated here as

```
s != (0 & d) <= N
```

which is probably not what was intended.

You need to use `&&` and `||` for the equivalent of Python's `and` and `or` operators. These operators perform short-circuit evaluation ([documentation](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/control-flow/#man-short-circuit-evaluation)).

As in Python, comparisons (like `!=` and `<=`) have higher precedence than boolean operators, so you shouldn't need additional parentheses.

Comment: Thanks, I did actually try to use those, but, while using the if...break condition somenthing happens, using && doesn't seems to let the loop end and I have to force end the process.

Comment: Can you provide a small working example? It makes it easier to debug things.

Comment: The while is part of an if cycle that fill an array of which 's' is the length. The while should be continue until the array is not empty and its length is less than N . (s is equal to d in the code). I hope that I've been more clear. Thanks